# AWS tags keys and values?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags

Why tags in AWS have *key* and *value*? What is the meaning/difference of the *key* and the *value*? What is the advantage of having the *key* and the *value* instead of the just tag with one string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of the Key as a 'Topic', such as:

- **Department:** Finance
- **Project:** A-42
- **Expiry Date:** 2022-05-01

This allows very expressive information to be added to resources, rather than simple values.

In terms of programming, AWS tags are like 'Dictionaries' rather than 'Lists'.

Which is best? That depends on the use-case. However, I did notice that **Amazon Lightsail offers both types**:

[image: Amazon Lightsail tags]

Comment: Usually key/value pair have some meaning. For example, you can with key get the corresponding value in dictionary. So they have different functionality. I mean there is a difference between key and value and what they do. Am I understand correctly that at AWS they are only just two different parts of the tag and nothing more?

Comment: AWS Tags _are_ a dictionary.